# Merging/combining two two-dimensional associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I've searched SO and Google and found other questions similar to mine but I'm not able to translate the answers from those specific cases to my case.  So... I've got two arrays as shown below... Array 1 and Array 2.  I would like to combine them so they end up like the Final Array.

**Array 1**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12345
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 54321
        )

)
```

**Array 2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date_entered] => today
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date entered] => yesterday
        )

)
```

**Final Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12345
            [date_entered] => today
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 54321
            [date entered] => yesterday
        )

)
```

I tried to use `array_merge` as well as `array_merge_recursive` but it is not merging them how I want it:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12345
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 54321
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date_entered] => today
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date entered] => yesterday
        )

)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not so hard: http://3v4l.org/9b9k1

Comment: Thank you that worked!  I still need to sit and look at the code more and try to understand WHY it works.  I think I am still not completely comfortable with multidimensional arrays and manipulating them.  I need to spend more time studying them.  Thank you again!